# Which one connect method in Orbot I need to use?

Tags: orbot, proxy, android

In my workplace the Internet connection is proxied, some of websites and web-services won't load.

I tried to use Orbot with the address of proxy and proxy's port, it was unsuccessful.
Then with and without proxy-address in it, but with bridges. Unsuccesful too.
Then with default ip-tables and with all permutation of above, without any success.

I have installed Tor Browser on my laptop (uses same WLAN, as phone). In the Launcher screen I chose the ISP-limitless opportunity, then filled out the proxy-screen. Tor-browser started without mistakes.
In tools-options-advanced tab I saw, TB use socks5 proxy with `localhost:9150` address. In Orbot I tried `localhost:9050` (default port for socks) address /with and without restricted policies, with and without default ip tables,  without succes. Then changed the default port to 9150 in settings, and for the localhost-proxy. nope.

So i have too many variables to reach the internet with orbot on phone.
Wich one is the default possibility with a hard proxy-server?

Comment: To check, you went into Orbot -> Settings -> Outbound Network Proxy and set the same type, host, port and address for the proxy settings there as you configured Tor Browser to use? Both Orbot and Tor Browser don't differ in terms of how they'd connect using a proxy. What kind of proxy did you configure?

Comment: Hi! The connection have http/https proxy. So i need set up this proxy in Orbot-settings, without checked restricted policies?

Comment: the `http` proxy type is for using an http proxy to make directory requests, the `https` proxy type is for using an http proxy for connections to relays.

Comment: I have just one inner-range IP-address for proxy. (10.0.xx.xx)

Comment: O.K., this is https proxy. (with http-label the build of circuits stopped). So the Orbot connected to the Tor-network, i tap the "browse" button, orfox start, the orbot-indicator show the activity in the notification area (the arrows in it), and orfox says, proxy server has refused the connection.

Comment: What does the Orbot log show? Does the icon turn green? You can see the log lines by swiping in from the left side of the screen.

Comment: The phone only supports http proxy, not the socks, so just input the port 8118 after localhost, instead of 9050.